# PostgreSQL datasource URL?

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

My first attempt to use PostgreSQL:

I have the elephant icon on the top right: running on port 5432.

I want to use LibreOffice as an interface:

- Connect to an existing database: PostgreSQL
- Datasource URL: ???

What should I put here? The database will be on the same computer where LibreOffice is running. Tried with `localhost:5432` with no success.
By the way, I did not create the database, yet. Can I do it from LibreOffice?

Thank you.

Platform: 
  Mac OSX 10.7 - PostgreSQL 9.2.2 - LibreOffice 4.0

Comment: You need at least running a db cluster before you can connect. Since you have to connect to a particular *database*, you can use `template1` which is always there or `postgres` (at least on Debian derivatives) as long as you haven't created yours, yet.

Answer (score 2):

From [ask.libreoffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/459/generic-form-of-url-for-postgresql/?answer=463#post-id-463), [as linked on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/463639/11116)

> With the native postgreSQL connector the connection string is a little
>   different. It is not a URL at all, but rather just a text string made
>   up of propertyname=value segments, separated by a space.
>
> The required fields (properties) are, database name and host (or
>   hostaddr). If the postgreSQL database is using a non standard port
>   (5432) then that must be included also.
>
> So, if I want to connect to a database, using the default postgres
>   configuration, named postgres on my local machine the simplest
>   connection string would be: dbname=postgres host=localhost
>
> Now let's say that there is an older postgres engine running using the
>   standard 5432 port and I want to connect to a newer one using port
>   5433, and that I want to connect with my user name db_user, with a
>   password of libreoffice and I don't want to type that password in each
>   time I connect, then the connection string might look like:
>
> ```
> dbname=postgres hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5433 user=db_user password=libreoffice
> ```
>
> Note that I've used the hostaddr, instead of host here, bypassing any
>   need to do a DNS lookup.
>
> Finally, with the native connector all options in the connection
>   string are accepted - you can find a full list of those here:
>   [PostgreSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html) Just remember that it is propertyName=value
>   separated by spaces in Base.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to [How do I connect to a PostgreSQL server using LibreOffice Base?](https://superuser.com/q/391242) on SuperUser, [txindoki](https://superuser.com/users/119016/txindoki) wrote:

> This is not an Internet URL, but it functions similarly. You now need
>   to tell LibreOffice to connect to a specific database on a specific
>   computer:
>
> `dbname=mydb host=localhost`
>
> Use the name of your database in the dbname part. I used localhost for
>   the host part, since PostgreSQL is on the same computer, but I would
>   need to change that in the event that I want to connect from a remote
>   computer.

Another form of datasource URL is in the format of:

`dbname=postgres hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5433 user=db_user password=db_pass`